# How can I write entity history records to another server？

Tags: hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

I want write entity to server1, but entity history to server2, how do I config my datasource?
Did anyone particular it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple `DataSource` configuration that you could use.
The `DataSource` would need to analyse SQL statements in order to decide to which server to send them. You probably could implement something like this yourself, by searching for the names of the history tables in the SQL statements, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Assuming your database supports this it seems more appropriate to use [database link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm#ADMIN12083) or some comparable technology, which allows you to write to the same database but have the data actually end up on the second server.